# Add to cart maximun quantity per product with validation in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, cart

I want to restrict add to cart button with a max quantity of 10 per product. I want customers cannot purchase more than 10 quantity per product per order.

Here is the code

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'restrict_per_product_quantity' );
function restrict_per_product_quantity($cart_item_data) {
    global $woocommerce;
    $item_count = $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count;
    if($item_count > 10) {
        wc_add_notice( 'Sorry, Only 10 quantity per product per order is allowed. If you would like to order more please contact support.', 'error' );
        return false;
    }
    return $cart_item_data;
}
```

---

The issue is this code did not work with per product, it checks the cart, and if there are 10 items in the cart it displays the error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- `woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation` contains 5 parameters that you can use
- explanation via comments added in the code

```php
function filter_woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation( $passed, $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id = null, $variations = null ) {
    // Set max allowed
    $max_allowed = 10;
    
    // Error message
    $message = 'max ' . $max_allowed . ' products allowed';
    
    // quantity > max allowed || elseif = when cart not empty
    if ( $quantity > $max_allowed ) {
        wc_add_notice( __( $message, 'woocommerce' ), 'error' );
        $passed = false;   
    } elseif ( ! WC()->cart->is_empty() ) {
        // Get current product id
        $product_id = $variation_id > 0 ? $variation_id : $product_id;
    
        // Cart id
        $product_cart_id = WC()->cart->generate_cart_id( $product_id );
    
        // Find product in cart
        $in_cart = WC()->cart->find_product_in_cart( $product_cart_id );
        
        // True
        if ( $in_cart ) {
            // Get cart
            $cart = WC()->cart->get_cart();

            // Current quantity in cart
            $quantity_in_cart = $cart[$product_cart_id]['quantity'];
            
            // Condition: quanitity in cart + new add quantity greater than max allowed
            if ( $quantity_in_cart + $quantity > $max_allowed ) {           
                wc_add_notice( __( $message, 'woocommerce' ), 'error' );
                $passed = false;
            }
        }
    }
    
    return $passed;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'filter_woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 10, 5 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use these hooks to set minimum and maximum Quantity for product.

```
<?php
    
    /*
    * Changing the minimum quantity to 2 for all the WooCommerce products
    */
    
    function woocommerce_quantity_input_min_callback( $min, $product ) {
        $min = 2;  
        return $min;
    }
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_min', 'woocommerce_quantity_input_min_callback', 10, 2 );
    
    /*
    * Changing the maximum quantity to 5 for all the WooCommerce products
    */
    
    function woocommerce_quantity_input_max_callback( $max, $product ) {
        $max = 5;  
        return $max;
    }
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_max', 'woocommerce_quantity_input_max_callback', 10, 2 );
    ?>
   [![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

Comment: This works if the product is simple. If the product has variations, after choosing which ones you want, it allows you to insert more than the `$max` allowed function.