# Set Max quantity allowed of product added to cart to 6 with notice

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, cart

I've tried several variations of this so far. I am trying to set the max quantity of any single product, or variable product variation at a maximum of 6 for purchase. I'm using [Add to cart maximun quantity per product with validation in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63896508/11987538) answer code

the problem with this is:
it doesn't check on the product page, instead, it allows it to be added to the cart at any quantity without an error message, then when you navigate to the cart it performs the check, automatically updates the cart (again no error message displaying why the cart updates to 6).

In case it's relevant I have also successfully added a function that allows no more than 6 to be added to the cart at a time.  (this doesn't help my issue because someone can just keep adding on the product page itself.

Source: [Adjust the quantity input values](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/adjust-the-quantity-input-values/)

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 'jk_woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 10, 2 ); // Simple products

function jk_woocommerce_quantity_input_args( $args, $product ) {
    if ( is_singular( 'product' ) ) {
        $args['input_value']    = 1;    // Starting value (we only want to affect product pages, not cart)
    }
    $args['max_value']  = 6;    // Maximum value
    $args['min_value']  = 1;    // Minimum value
    $args['step']       = 1;    // Quantity steps
    return $args;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'jk_woocommerce_available_variation' ); // Variations

function jk_woocommerce_available_variation( $args ) {
    $args['max_qty'] = 6;       // Maximum value (variations)
    $args['min_qty'] = 1;       // Minimum value (variations)
    return $args;
}
```

Comment: If you need to enforce the same logic on the product page itself, you could use/add ```is_product()``` conditional check.

Comment: @jmasked If you're using existing code, please always mention the source. That shows some respect for the person who wrote the code. By the way, I cannot reproduce: **"_the problem with this is: it doesn't check on the product page, instead, it allows it to be added to the cart at any quantity without an error message_"**. Since this is an accepted answer, you can assume that it works.

Comment: @7uc1f3r  with some troubleshooting, because no error messages were displaying I discovered this code actually didn't work.  We had already setup a cart function that was automatically updating a cart to 6 maximum if it wasn't being corrected on the product page.  So after removing the code, it functioned as I stated.  My apologies for not linking back to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can WC `woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation` filter hook where you can set max quantity and then check max quantity against product cart quantity. check below code. code will go to the active theme functions.php file.

```
/*
* Validating the quantity on add to cart action with the quantity of the same product available in the cart. 
*/
function show_error_on_max_quantity_reached( $passed, $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id = '', $variations = '' ) {

    $product_max = 6;

    $already_in_cart    = wc_qty_get_cart_qty( $product_id );
    $product            = wc_get_product( $product_id );
    $product_title      = $product->get_title();
    
    if ( !empty( $already_in_cart ) ) {
        
        if ( ( $already_in_cart + $quantity ) > $product_max ) {
            
            $passed = false;            

            wc_add_notice( 
                sprintf( __( 'Sorry, You can add a maximum of %1$s %2$s\'s to %3$s. You already have %4$s.', 'woocommerce-max-quantity' ), 
                    $product_max,
                    $product_title,
                    '<a href="' . esc_url( wc_get_cart_url() ) . '">' . __( 'Your cart', 'woocommerce-max-quantity' ) . '</a>',
                    $already_in_cart 
                ),
            'error' );

        }
    }

    return $passed;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'show_error_on_max_quantity_reached', 1, 5 );

/*
* Get the total quantity of the product available in the cart.
*/ 
function wc_qty_get_cart_qty( $product_id , $cart_item_key = '' ) {
    global $woocommerce;
    $running_qty = 0; // iniializing quantity to 0

    // search the cart for the product in and calculate quantity.
    foreach($woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $other_cart_item_keys => $values ) {
        if ( $product_id == $values['product_id'] ) {

            if ( $cart_item_key == $other_cart_item_keys ) {
                continue;
            }

            $running_qty += (int) $values['quantity'];
        }
    }

    return $running_qty;
}

Tested and works.
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for much for the response Bhautik.  This is now preventing more than 6 of any product to be added to cart.  Problems are: No error notice displaying, Also products with variations can have no more than 6 of any variation added.

Comment: So do you want to prevent more than 6 of each product?

Comment: Yes I want to prevent more than 6 of each product/6 of each product variation.  Plus an error message to display on product page like your picture.

Comment: Can you give example?